# Why is the following equation considered affine?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

From [Boyd and Vandenberghe - "Convex Optimization"](http://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf) question 3.20(b) and 3.20(c) state that

> $A_{0} + A_{1}x_{x} + \ldots + A_{n}x_{n}$ is an affine transformation on the set $\{x | A_{0} + \sum^{n}_{i}A_{i}x_{i} 
> \succeq 0\}$

How is this an affine transformation and is it only an affine transformation if $x$ makes the result semi-positive definite or would it still be an affine transformation for all $x$?

Comment: What does "given that $\{x | A_{0} + \sum^{n}_{i}A_{i}x_{i} 
\succeq 0\}$" mean? I refuse to believe that Boyd and Vandenberghe wrote something like that. That's like saying "Given that $5$" or "Given that apple".

Comment: @MishaLavrov you are correct, and the funny part is that OP linked the PDF which he cited. Page $42$ has the original statement.

Comment: @algevristis Thank you for pointing that out. I think I've corrected the citation to the intended meaning.